# Python removing outliers from plotly scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, outliers

I coloured my outliers already and they are shown in the plot. I can`t figure out how to remove the "weird" outliers from the plot?

## Flagging the weirdoes

```
weirdoes_condition = final['median [profitrate] of firms with [region = "N"]'] < 0.0185
print("nb of weirdoes", weirdoes_condition.sum())

final["regime"] = 'normal'
final.loc[weirdoes_condition, 'regime'] = 'weird'
final["regime"].value_counts()
nb of weirdoes 18
normal    117
weird      18
Name: regime, dtype: int64

fig = px.scatter(final, x='mean [agent_productivity] of households with [employer = "mine"]', y='mean [gamma] of mines', color='regime')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not clear on the intent of the question, but to exclude outliers and graph them in the data in advance. plotly only, the user can hide the outliers by clicking weird in the legend.